# Render svg-file in LibGDX

Tags: svg, libgdx, vector-graphics

Does libGDX support rendering vector graphics? I need to draw some simple *.svg files, but can't find how to load them. Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope it does not.

LibGDX provides you a way to draw simple shapes (implemented as [ShapeRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html)) but it cannot parse .svg probably due to being multiplatform.

Still you can use some 3rd part library designed for specify platform like [svg android](https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/)

---

Also take a look at this:

- [Thread #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322995/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-vector-graphics-into-libgdx-development)
- [Thread #2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/vector-images-svg-or-other-formats-support-in-libgdx-or-other-android-framewor)